# Best Method to Share Data Object Between Two Local iOS Apps

Tags: ios, ios8, url-scheme, data-sharing

I am looking for advice on what the best tool for the job is for sharing a relatively complex data object between two iOS apps on the same device.

I have a real estate investment app that we will call app A which allows the user to input data about a potential investment property and calculate important financial metrics such as ROI. All of the property data is persisted using Core Data in an object we will call Property.

I am developing app B which imports a Property Object from app A and creates a PDF report that the user can send to other investors. The Property object does not need to be persisted in app B, only used temporarily to create the pdf file. I would like the user to be able to open up app A from app B and choose a property, similar to a photo picker.

My initial instinct is to use URL schemes to solve this problem. Is this the best solution for my needs?

Comment: Would a `UIDocumentInteractionController` work for your needs to generate the PDF in App A and pass it to App B instead of App B generating the PDF? Just throwing this out, as it's relatively simple to work with and implement. You can even email the PDF right within the `UIDocumentInteractionController` in App A, possibly meaning you don't even need an App B at all! I could be wrong though if I mis-understand your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't many options and what few there are really require that both apps be developed by the same developer (which appears to be the case here).

The easiest is to used a shared, private, named pasteboard (`UIPasteboard`) in conjunction with custom URL schemes.

App A can put the data in the pasteboard and then launch app B using its custom URL scheme. Of course both apps must be coded to understand how the data is written to the pasteboard and on the name of the pasteboard. Though the name of the pasteboard could be passed as part of the custom URL.

Once app B generates the PDF, the reverse process can happen. App B can put the PDF into the pasteboard and then launch app A using its custom URL scheme. Then app A can get the PDF from the pasteboard and present it to the user.

Or, if it makes sense, app B can use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to let the user choose what to do with the PDF. That is certainly up to your needs.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution. I found a great tutorial on this approach here http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, I am referring to the custom pasteboard with URL schemes